# Problem with fontspec and EBGaramond

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

Im trying to typeset a book using fontspec and the [EB Garamond font](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/index.html). I try first to use Lualatex because I wanted to experiment with some features of the impnattypo (french typography) package. However, at first I had some problems rendering OpenType features like historic ligatures, small caps in conjuction with caps to small caps, and almost all the contextual alternatives. Then, I found suggestions about a problem with lualatex, so I changed to XeLaTeX, and some of my problems got fixed, but some of them not. For example, I can't activate historic ligatures, I can't get the alternative "1" (feature cv11), and the TeX ligatures (--- and such) don't work. Here is a working example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[11pt,DIV=8]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[papersize={140mm,210mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={+hlig,+clig,+dlig,+cv11,+cv90,+calt,+ccmp,+swsh},Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}}

%Cool Small caps
\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

%first paragrpaph definition
\newcommand{\primero}[1]{\noindent{\smallcaps{#1}}}

% cool french typography 
\usepackage[    hyphenation,
            parindent,
            lastparline
            ]{impnattypo}

\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines

% footers and headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % except the center
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small{\smallcaps{Some Author}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\small{\smallcaps{Some Title For This}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}

% chapter start
\renewcommand*\sectfont{\rmfamily\scshape}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}
Quienes queriendo. \textit{Quienes quieren querer queriendo.} 

---This should be an em-dash,and the ligature in this: Th should work. 

--This should be an en-dash and this historic ligatures should work: estaba octubre. 

--- These ones should not look like roman numerals: 111111. 

\kant[1]

\textit{\kant[2]}
\end{document}
```

I tried the options in the fontspec manual, and also tried the suggestions from the font author's own [specimen data](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/blob/master/specimen/Specimen.pdf?raw=true) and his [recommendations for XeLaTeX use](https://raw.github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/master/README.xelualatex). I also tried using `Mapping=tex-text` and `Ligatures=TeX` with no success. I also tried changing from Raw OpenType features to fontspec defined features (like Ligatures={Historic}.

I don't know what else to do. I have scrambled around with this file all day with no success. And the worst thing is that I know I made it work before! but now I can't remeber how... :( I know there must be some little and obvious thing that I'm missing.

Comment: Have you tried setting the default font features before setting the main font?

Comment: _D-OH!_ Of course! thanks! fool of me....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare the default font features *before* setting the font with `\setmainfont`.
Also make sure you didn't somehow end up with the TrueType version of the font.

Furthermore, it might be worthwhile to specify the files in more detail:

```
\setmainfont
    [ Path        = /path/to/fonts/ ,
      Extension   = .otf,
      UprightFont = *12-Regular  ,
      ItalicFont  = *12-Italic ,
      BoldFont    = *08-Regular ]
    {EBGaramond}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and now I know that I should do that. However, I'm pretty sure I'm using the OTF files (because I installed just those) and I wanted to let the system select automatically the correct optical size (12 for 11pt and higer sizes, 08 for 10 and lower sizes. It now works wonderfully! :)