# fontspec and EB Garamond: Cannot use EBGaramond12-Italic

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ebgaramond, optical-size

I dowloaded EB Garamond from https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/releases/tag/nightly and copied all fonts, .otf and .ttf to `~/.fonts/e`

The typeface contains different font files for the optical sizes 08pt and 12pt:

[image]

However, if I create a document which should contain EBGaramond12-Italic and compile it with LuaLaTeX, my PDF reader only shows the following fonts:

[image]

```tex
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79783/38905
\setmainfont[%
SizeFeatures={%
    {Size={-12},
        Font=*08-Regular,
        ItalicFont=*08-Italic},
    {Size={12-},
        Font=*12-Regular,
        ItalicFont=*12-Italic}
},
]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
    \normalsize
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    
    \huge
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    
    \normalsize
    \textit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
    
    \huge
    \textit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} 
\end{document}
```

This is how the PDF looks:

[image]

This was compiled with

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
Development id: 7509
```

Why doesn't this work as expected and how can I work around this issue?

Comment: Good question! I do not see anything wrong with the code. Hopefully a more knowledgeable user will find this question and answer it. Meanwhile: Is there any chance that you have only some of the EBGaramond fonts installed in a different directory, and fontspec is finding that directory instead of where you placed the downloads? Did you try `luaotfload-tool --cache=erase` followed by `luaotfload-tool -u` ? Not sure if you need to precede that code with `mktexlsr` (probably not).

Comment: I checked and they're not in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`

I noticed this in the lualatex output
`</home/username/.fonts/e/EBGaramond08-Italic.otf></home/username/.fonts/e/EBG
aramond12-Regular.otf></home/username/.fonts/e/EBGaramond08-Regular.otf>`

`luaotfload-tool` did not fix this.

Comment: In the log file, there is a difference between the normal and italic variant:

`(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <-12>"EBGaramond08-Regular:mode=node;script=latn;languag
e=dflt;+tlig;"<12->"EBGaramond12-Regular:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+t
lig;"

(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"EBGaramond/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tl
ig;"`

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.texlive2022/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65087/38905) and `rm -rf ~/.cache/texmf/fonts` didn't help either.

Comment: If I manually search it, luaotftool does find it:

`$ luaotfload-tool --find=EBGaramond12-Regular
luaotfload | resolve : Font "EBGaramond12-Regular" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/home/username/.fonts/e/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf"
$ luaotfload-tool --find=EBGaramond12-Italic
luaotfload | resolve : Font "EBGaramond12-Italic" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/home/username/.fonts/e/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf"`

Comment: `fc-list | sort | grep -i "EBGaramond` shows that EBGaramond12-Italic contains fewer "attributes" than EBGaramond08-Italic:

https://pastebin.com/raw/xDMiW7FK

Maybe that's why one can find it with luaotfload manually, but not automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fontspec` manual says about using `SizeFeatures` with `ItalicFeatures`:

> **Interaction with other features** For `SizeFeatures` to work with `ItalicFeatures`, `BoldFeatures`,
> etc., and `SmallCapsFeatures`, a strict heirarchy(sic) is required:
>
> ```
> UprightFeatures =
>   {
>     SizeFeatures =
>       {
>         {
>           Size = -10,
>           Font = ..., % if necessary
>           SmallCapsFeatures = {...},
>           ... % other features for this size range
>         },
>         ... % other size ranges
>       }
>   }
> ```

While not explicitly mentioned, the same principle applies to `ItalicFont`: The font shape (like italic or upright) is applied first, before size processing, so you need to follow specific orders when combining them.

Here you can do this by moving the italic fonts into the `SizeFeatures` of the `ItalicFeatures`:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
  SizeFeatures={%
    {Size={-12}, Font=*08-Regular},
    {Size={12-}, Font=*12-Regular},
  },
  ItalicFeatures={%
    SizeFeatures={%
      {Size={-12}, Font=*08-Italic},
      {Size={12-}, Font=*12-Italic},
    },
  },
]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
    \normalsize
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    
    \huge
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    
    \normalsize
    \textit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
    
    \huge
    \textit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The code in your answer is the same as in my question, though.

Comment: @804b18f832fb419fb142 Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 5):

Invoking `\setmainfont{...}` this way gives the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[
  UprightFeatures={
    SizeFeatures={
      {Size={12-},Font=ebgaramond12regular},
      {Size={-12},Font=ebgaramond08regular}
    }},
  ItalicFeatures={
    SizeFeatures={
      {Size={12-},Font=ebgaramond12italic},
      {Size={-12},Font=ebgaramond08italic}
    }}]
\begin{document}
\normalsize
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

\huge
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

\normalsize
\textit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\huge
\textit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Even when one specifies the fonts like this:

`[
UprightFeatures={
 SizeFeatures={
  {Size={12-},Font=*12-Regular},
  {Size={-12},Font=*08-Regular}
}},
ItalicFeatures={
 SizeFeatures={
  {Size={12-},Font=*12-Italic},
  {Size={-12},Font=*08-Italic}
}}]`